# How to get Apache's running request at a specific moment?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, html-parsing

I need to find a way to get all Apache running request at a given moment. I need to list the vhost, cpu, request ip address and some other information.
This information will be consumed by a PHP script.

I have **mod_status** installed and it has all the information I need. So I tried to use file_get_contents to get the report, generating a request from the server (http://localhost/server-status). It worked perfectly. Then I tried to parse the report, converting it to XML using simplexml_load_string. The problem is that the HTML outputted by mod_status is not well formed.

Here is the HTL from the table I need to parse:

```
<table border="0"><tr><th>Srv</th><th>PID</th><th>Acc</th><th>M</th><th>CPU
</th><th>SS</th><th>Req</th><th>Conn</th><th>Child</th><th>Slot</th><th>Client</th><th>VHost</th><th>Request</th></tr>

<tr><td><b>0-1</b></td><td>-</td><td>0/0/70</td><td>.
</td><td>0.00</td><td>107</td><td>0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.34
</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td nowrap>zsce</td><td nowrap>OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0</td></tr>

<tr><td><b>1-1</b></td><td>-</td><td>0/0/55</td><td>.
</td><td>0.04</td><td>108</td><td>0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.70
</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td nowrap>zsce</td><td nowrap>OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0</td></tr>

</table>
```

I'm sure someone has tried to do something like this before.
1) Is there another way to access the information I need?
2) Has anybody tried other tools / modules?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that if I remove "nowrap" from the HTML before parsing it, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the problem with the HTML. What's wrong with it?

Does PHP not have a liberal HTML parser; something like Python's BeautifulSoup or Ruby's Nokogiri?

Also, remember that mod_status has 'auto' mode for producing machine-readable output.

http://www.apache.org/server-status?auto
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html#machinereadable

Comment: thanks for your response. The error I'm getting in PHP is: "E: Specification mandate value for attribute nowrap."  because the values at the end of each row of the table are not been closed by a tag. I'm going to check machine-readable output. tks.

Comment: I'm very surprised to see such a strict error from your parser. This html as generated by mod_status is probably rather old fashioned (html3 maybe) but I'd expect such an issue to be a warning, not an error.